# How to copy material settings from one object to another

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine

I have a huge amount of image planes, each has a different image linked to the base color, the texture applied is a png with alpha, in order to make the alpha work in EEVEE I need to change the material settings Blend Mode to Alpha Blend, and Shadow Mode to Alpha Hashed, by default both are set to Opaque.
I changed this for one of the materials, but going through this manually for each image plane is not pratical, is there a way to copy the material settings only without having to copy the whole material?

Comment: generally the way to do it is to select all the object, go in the settings, select the setting you want, and alt enter, but it doesn't seem to work for the Blend mode...

Comment: Are you sure about this method, I tried it for the Specular and still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a little script for you. Just select all the planes and run the script. (It assumes that each plane has only 1 material)

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    m = obj.data.materials[0]
    m.blend_method = 'BLEND'
    m.shadow_method = 'HASHED'
```

Comment: Great, many thanks